# x86_64-pc-mingw64 error compiling hmmer software

Tags: bioinformatics, syslog

I am using git for windows and make from chocolatey but the issue I have I believe is when running `make` I get an error when it enters the easel.c file I get an error below on line 39 which is `#include <syslog.h>`

Why do I get this error?  I hope somebody from HMMER can tell me.

EDITING AFTER ADDING syslog.h from [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/asankah/syslog-win32/master/syslog.h)

```
hmmer-3.2$ make
     SUBDIR easel
     CC easel.o
easel.c:39:20: fatal error: syslog.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [Makefile:521: easel.o] Error 1
make: *** [Makefile:87: all] Error 2
```

EDITS:
Now after I added the syslog.h file from source I get these errors from the `esl_buffer.c` file.  Wonder if HMMER tested this on Windows?

```
hmmer-3.2$ make
     SUBDIR easel
     CC esl_buffer.o
esl_buffer.c: In function 'esl_buffer_Close':
esl_buffer.c:523:4: warning: implicit declaration of function 'munmap' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
esl_buffer.c: In function 'buffer_init_file_mmap':
esl_buffer.c:1575:3: warning: implicit declaration of function 'mmap' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
esl_buffer.c:1575:34: error: 'PROT_READ' undeclared (first use in this function)
esl_buffer.c:1575:34: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
esl_buffer.c:1575:45: error: 'MAP_PRIVATE' undeclared (first use in this function)
esl_buffer.c:1576:18: error: 'MAP_FAILED' undeclared (first use in this function)
make[1]: *** [Makefile:521: esl_buffer.o] Error 1
make: *** [Makefile:87: all] Error 2
```